# Example of limiting a vertex from being dragged outside a polygon in OpenLayers6

Tags: polygon, javascript, openlayers

I have the following situation:

The base polygon is where I defined that all other polygons should be drawn.

When using the draw interaction, setting the condition option is enough to limit where the point is placed on the map (in my case, the base polygon).

The problem is when I'm modifying them. I can drag a vertex outside the base polygon and I want to disable that behaviour but I can't find any solution to that.

If I use the same condition option from the draw interaction on the modify interaction, it disables the dragging only after the vertex was placed.

So my problem comes down to disabling drag outside a specified polygon for any polygon inside it.

Comment: Coding question on GIS SE site should include relevant existing code, otherwise it's most likely to be closed as not compliant with the site policy. Please [edit](https://gis.stackexchange.com/posts/413388/edit) your question and add relevant existing code.

Comment: @TomazicM I just need a basic example of solving this specific problem... it's not related to my code.

Comment: Existing code is always relevant and should be included, otherwise scenario usually goes like this: "Yes, but my need/code is different, since I have/would like ... Wouldn't it be possible ..."

Comment: answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69479156/example-of-limiting-a-vertex-from-being-dragged-outside-a-polygon-in-openlayers6)